# Type '() => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>' cannot be used as an index type [ReactJs]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I currently am working on a control panel for a page that loads up a list of cards.

I have two different routes from an API that are as follows:

```
const apiVideoUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
const apiManualUrl = "http://localhost:3000/manuals/";
```

They both return sets of data that are displayed as cards, and they both contain Id, Title, URL and ThumbnailUrl. I've been successful with just loading either videos or manuals seperately, but I Cannot seem to get them to load up together.

my componentDidMount() is as follows and is where the error is arrising from:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const apiVideoUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const apiManualUrl = "http://localhost:3000/manuals/";

    const getVideos = async () => {
      return await axios.get(apiVideoUrl);
    };

    const getManuals = async () => {
      return await axios.get(apiManualUrl);
    };

    try {
      const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.all[(getVideos, getManuals)];

      // render to state setState({ prop: ? })
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }
```

The error:

```
Type '() => Promise<AxiosResponse<any>>' cannot be used as an index type.ts(2538)
```

is given from:

```
  const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.all[(getVideos, getManuals)];
```

The code for the rest of the page  is as follows (just incase it's needed):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import HelpCard from "./HelpCard";
import "../help/HelpCard.css";
import axios from "axios";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroller";

interface State {
  url: string;
  title: string;
  adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard[];
  error: null;
  response: {};
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface SingleAdminHelpCard {
  id: string;
  url: string;
  title: string;
  thumbnail: string;
}

interface Props {}

export default class HelpList extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    title: "",
    thumbnail: "",
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {}
  };

  loadAdminHelpCard = () => {
    axios
      .get(this.state.url)
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => {
          const adminhelpcard = prevState.adminhelpcard;
          return {
            adminhelpcard: [...prevState.adminhelpcard, ...res.data],
            url: res.data.next
          };
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
  static props: any;

  async componentDidMount() {
    const apiVideoUrl = "http://localhost:3000/videos/";
    const apiManualUrl = "http://localhost:3000/manuals/";

    const getVideos = async () => {
      return await axios.get(apiVideoUrl);
    };

    const getManuals = async () => {
      return await axios.get(apiManualUrl);
    };

    try {
      const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.all[(getVideos, getManuals)];

      // render to state setState({ prop: ? })
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({ error });
    }
  }

  deleteProduct(id: any) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;

    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;
    const apiManualUrl = `http://localhost:3000/manuals/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "DELETE"
    };

    fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
    fetch(apiManualUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );

    console.log(this.state.id);
  }

  editProduct(id: any, title: string, url: string, thumbnail: string) {
    const { adminhelpcard } = this.state;
    const apiVideoUrl = `http://localhost:3000/videos/${id}`;
    const apiManualUrl = `http://localhost:3000/manuals/${id}`;

    const options = {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        url,
        thumbnail
      })
    };

    fetch(apiVideoUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
    fetch(apiManualUrl, options)
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          this.setState({
            response: result,
            adminhelpcard: adminhelpcard.filter((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard) => adminhelpcard.id !== id)
          });
        },
        (error) => {
          this.setState({ error });
        }
      );
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.adminhelpcard);
    return (
      <div>
        <React.Fragment>
          {this.state.adminhelpcard ? (
            <div className="row">
              <InfiniteScroll
                pageStart={1}
                loadMore={this.loadAdminHelpCard}
                hasMore={this.state.url ? true : false}
                threshold={0}
                loader={
                  <div className="loader" key={0}>
                    Loading ...
                  </div>
                }>
                {this.state.adminhelpcard.map((adminhelpcard: SingleAdminHelpCard, i) => (
                  <HelpCard
                    id={adminhelpcard.id}
                    key={adminhelpcard.id + i}
                    title={adminhelpcard.title}
                    url={adminhelpcard.url}
                    thumbnail={adminhelpcard.thumbnail}
                    deleteProduct={this.deleteProduct.bind(this)}
                    editProduct={this.editProduct.bind(this)}
                  />
                ))}
              </InfiniteScroll>
            </div>
          ) : (
            <h1>Loading Cards</h1>
          )}
        </React.Fragment>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

What is triggering this error and for what reason?

--------------------------EDIT----------------------------------
This is the return of the console.log

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e.mp4",
        "title": "How to train your dragon video",
        "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/l3uyjXJl2Fw/hqdefault.jpg"
      },
      {
        "title": "Guide - Web",
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-6928.mp4",
        "thumbnail": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/Um3BhY0oS2c/hqdefault.jpg",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "title": "Reports - Non-Supervisors",
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-Videos+1263198.mp4",
        "thumbnail": "",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-Videos+1263198.mp4",
        "title": " - Non-Supervisors",
        "thumbnail": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-Videos+1263198.mp4",
        "title": " - Non-Supervisors",
        "thumbnail": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-198.mp4",
        "title": "Supervisors",
        "thumbnail": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-deos+1263198.mp4",
        "title": "Supervisors",
        "thumbnail": ""
      }
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "expires": "-1"
    },
    "config": {
      "transformRequest": {},
      "transformResponse": {},
      "timeout": 0,
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength": -1,
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      "method": "get",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/videos/"
    },
    "request": {}
  },
  {
    "data": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "url": "https://s3.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/ts-ui.e-ite.pdf",
        "title": "How to train your dragon",
        "thumbnail": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "url": "https://onaws.com/ts-ui.e-s.pdf",
        "title": "How to train your dragon test3",
        "thumbnail": ""
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "url": "https://sm/ts-ui.e-ide.pdf",
        "title": "Resume full guide",
        "thumbnail": ""
      }
    ],
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
      "pragma": "no-cache",
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      "cache-control": "no-cache",
      "content-length": "634",
      "expires": "-1"
    },
    "config": {
      "transformRequest": {},
      "transformResponse": {},
      "timeout": 0,
      "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
      "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
      "maxContentLength": -1,
      "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*"
      },
      "method": "get",
      "url": "http://localhost:3000/manuals/"
    },
    "request": {}
  }
]
```

Comment: bot getVideos and getManuals are uselssly async, just write: `const getVideos = () => \axios.get(apiVideoUrl);` Can you log videos and manuals after `const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.All([getVideos(), getManuals()])` Maybe in formatted JSON and post (some of) it in the question? `console.log(JSON.stringify([videos,manuals],undefined,2))`

Comment: @HMR I have added the log to my question. Returns all the appropriate sets of data, but only displays the Videos

Comment: It looks like manuals is there correctly. How do you set videos and manuals with setState?

Comment: @HMR If you look at the top of the code I have set, when I declare url: I only set the videos one but that's because I wasn't sure how I could add manuals and videos to both be url.

Comment: I only see `// render to state setState({ prop: ? })` in the componentDidMount code you posted.

Comment: @HMR I dont get what you mean, are you referring to this? 
state = {
    title: "",
    thumbnail: "",
    id: "",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/videos/",
    adminhelpcard: [],
    itemsCountPerPage: 1,
    activePage: 1,
    error: null,
    response: {}
  };

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200921/discussion-between-zadders-and-hmr).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In:

`const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.all[(getVideos, getManuals)];`

There is an Error on Promise. The syntax is Promise.All([])

You can use:
`const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.All([getVideos(), getManuals()])`

Read if you don't get it: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: In addition to this, OP should call the functions `getVideos` and `getManuals`: `await Promise.All([getVideos(), getManuals()])`

Comment: Thx El Aoutar Hamza. Sorry my typo. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @MarcoQuintella Writing this code seems to only display the cards from getVideos() and not getManuals()?

Answer (score 3):

You seem to just misspell brackets.

```
const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.all[(getVideos, getManuals)];
```

If you want to wait getVideos and getManuals resolved, you should call method *Promise.all* (with parenthesis) and pass Iteralbe as an argument (with square brackets):

```
const [videos, manuals] = await Promise.all([getVideos(), getManuals()]);
```

If you want to use values of promises right here, you can write code like:

```
Promise.all([getVideos(), getManuals()]).then(([videos, manuals]) => { /* do stuff */ });
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Writing this code seems to only display the cards from getVideos() and not getManuals()?

Comment: Indeed the first version of my answer gave you asynchronously resolved Promise as the iterable argument contained only references to methods getVideos and getManuals. But I have now fixed that. And Promise.all must return a single Promise that resolves when getVideos() and getManuals() have resolved. Or rejects, when either getVideos() or getManuals() rejects. If you want to do something with got values, use method "then". I'm going to improve my answer